Sending thousands Alerts
We want to send alert using institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/alert/send/generic to lets say 10k users and more in few minutes.
Will Admin API handle that amount of requests in very short time? Won't our system be blocked because it is "spamming"?

There is a not a publically documented rate limit for the institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/alert/send/generic endpoint, we may change this in the future. However, your described use case of sending 10,000+ alerts will likely hit a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests status code quickly.
As an alternative, there is also the Institution Messages endpoints which allows for mass messaging all users, as well as targeting specific segments of users. These messages are not customized to each recipient, they are great for generic alerts (updated holiday hours, for example). This set of endpoints is specifically designed for sending mass alerts, in bulk, as described.

Do you know which is  the default value for the Alert API rate limit (E.g: 5 request per second..)? Our business need to use that API but we can't found the default rate limit in any document.

There is a not a publicly documented rate limit.

It's not publicly documented, but there should be a default rate limit, correct? Should we configure the client to throttle requests proactively, or should we rely on handling 429 response statuses? Will the response include a Retry-After header or something similar?

It may be more helpful for your to explain your use case for a more tailored recommendation. The original answer is still the best I can offer in terms of rate limits.

The use case is straightforward: we have a large group of users (may be thousands) running the same campaign. When each user reaches their target, they will receive a personalized push notification to inform their achievement. The number of users reaching this milestone at any given time is unknown, but it could be thousands in a short period. Therefore, if the API has a rate limit, we’ll need to throttle calls to the API to manage the load effectively.
